# Hide few fields in django view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I want to dynamically show/hide fields of django forms in views.
Currently i am able to disable fields from views and able to dynamically render fields but cannot hide (without consuming field space in html).

For example i have address field in django form and i am disabling like below in view

```
    registration_form.initial['address'] = register[0]['address']
    registration_form.fields['address'].disabled = True
```

To hide field i have tried below but it occupies space of field in html

```
    registration_form.initial['address'] = register[0]['address']
    registration_form.fields['address'].widget = HiddenInput()
```

How can i hide field from django form?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included your views and forms

Comment: What about to exclude field from form?

Comment: Need to show fields for new user but for old users fields should be hidden so that information is not revealed. So cannot exclude fields from django form